# .hide() not working on ModalPopupExtender in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, show-hide, modalpopupextender

I am binding an onClick event in the document.ready() function to an image, and I want it to first hide the modalpopupextender that it should show and then execute a new function that shows a dialog.  the functionality works fine in IE, but doesn't in firefox or chrome.  I've seen this suggestion all over the internet and it just doesn't work for me.

```
//Change onClick events of links and images to return ProspectDisabled function
$("[id$='lnkAssignAccounts']").unbind("click");
$("[id$='lnkAssignAccounts']").bind("click",function(){
    $find('mpeAssignAccounts').hide();
    //$(".AssignAccountModal").hide();
    //$(".AssignAccountModal").css("display","none");
    return ProspectDisabled();
});
```

I've tried all of the above to hide by class, to change the .css to not display, to find the MPE and hide it, none of the above work, I've also mixed and match with .hide() and classes but that doesn’t' work either.  Kind of at stand still, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or higher, you should try changing .bind() to .click(); because .bind() is deprecate in jQuery 1.7+

so change this line:

```
$("[id$='lnkAssignAccounts']").bind("click",function(){
```

to this"

```
$("[id$='lnkAssignAccounts']").click(function(){
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello @Elon thank you for your response and i will adjust those bind click declarations, but the question was more geared towards why i can't hide the modalPopup or modalPopupExtender in Firefox or chome with the above code but it works fine in IE, if you could help on that i'd appreciate it.